# How Wix.com or Blogspot.com work for custom domain?

Tags: iis, dns, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I want to know how blogspot.com or wordpress.com or Wix.com work. I mean user can create a sub-domain on it and than can connect a custom domain to that sub-domain.

I want to create a dynamic functionality like blogspot.com where my user can create site like user1.mySite.com and then should be able to point their own custom domain (www.userwebsite.com) to user1.mySite.com without masking as we usually do in blogspot.com whenever user enter www.userwebsite.com they actually navigate to user1.blogspot.com.

How to achieve this via DNS or anything else? I use IIS Server.

Comment: But how to make it unable to connect my server for every individual user to allow to connect their custom domain can you elaborate?  How it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need three things (a) a web server that listens to all requests directed to it, and (b) a vhost that sends all server traffic to one script (e.g. a PHP script), and (c) some code that looks at the hostname in the request headers.

The simplest way of getting a web server to listen to all requests is to use the default vhost that catches all requests on port 80 (or 443 if you're using HTTPS with a certificate). You will need root access to your web server to do this (shared hosting does not give you enough flexibility).

Subdomains like `user1.mySite.com` are under your control, so you can either send a programmatic message to your DNS server to create an entry pointing to your web server's IP address, or you can use a [wildcard domain entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) to do the same automatically. You will need to host your own DNS server for this, or find a DNS provider with an HTTP-based API.

If someone turns up with `www.userwebsite.com` then they will need to amend it to point to your web server's IP, and you cannot do that since you do not have control of their DNS.